# inline code format as in TeX StackExchange

Tags: formatting, code

I'm trying to get an inline code format just like this `this`. [This answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/19004/how-to-format-an-inline-source-code) works but it's not near the format I'm looking for, and [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/583310/insert-inline-code-block-in-latex-document) gets a bit closer but it seems a too complex solution. A specific example of how I'm going to use it would be:

> We can make this random variable $X\sim N(\mu,\sigma^{2})$ with this
> function `my_normal_function(arg1, arg2, arg3)` given that..

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

How about using `tcolorbox`? It provides support for `\lstinline`. Refer to the documentation for more details.

```tex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[listings]{tcolorbox}

\lstdefinestyle{inlinepy}{%
    language=python,
    basicstyle=\ttfamily,
    commentstyle=\color{green!60!black},
    keywordstyle=\color{blue}\bfseries,
    stringstyle=\color{red},
    keepspaces=true,
}

\DeclareTotalTCBox{\inlinepy}{sv}{verbatim}{\lstinline[style=inlinepy]|#2|}

\begin{document}
    \begin{itemize}
        \item Python strings: \inlinepy{name = "First name" + "Last name"}
        \item Comments: \inlinepy{theta_rad = theta_deg*3.14/180 # angle conversion to radians}
        \item Import packages: \inlinepy{import numpy as np}
    \end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

[image]